# Pointers and Square Brackets

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having difficulty parsing this line of code:

```
int *a=new int[N];
```

So this declares a new integer pointer called "a", and wherever it points to will store a new pointer which points to objects of size (int+N). This is because

```
int[N]:=*(int+N)
```

The problem with this is that N is an instance of the class size_t, so how does the addition make sense? The full code is below:

```
int main()
{
const std::size_t N = 100;
int* a = new int[N];

for (std::size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n)
    a[n] = n;

delete[] a;
}
```

Comment: `a` points to an `int`. That `int` is the first in a contiguous range of `int`s of size `N`. And `std::size_t` is not a class. It has to be an integral type.

Comment: oh - so the right is a new array? should this be understood in terms of arrays or pointers?

Comment: You could call it a pointer to a free store array. Pointer to array could be ambiguous with `int(*)[N]`.

Comment: You could just leave all this arcane C crap behind and use `std::vector<int> a(N);` you know? ;)

Comment: I'm trying to understand and play around with the structure of a class, so that I can easily pick up new classes. I just thought that playing around with "class array" would be a good beginner's starting point.

Comment: @David, There are no classes in your code. Primitive types are not classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're treating `int[N]` as though it's an array access, like `array[5]` is the same as `*(array + 5)`. That's not what it is. After all, `int` is a type.

`new int[N]` is actually an expression that allocates an array of `N` `int`s. It returns a pointer to the first `int` in that array, which you are then assigning to `a`.

It's worth noting that every expression like this should be coupled with a `delete[]`, which is responsible for deallocating the array when you're done with it (just like every normal `new` should have a `delete`).

Answer (score 4):

> I'm having difficulty parsing this line of code:
>
> ```
> int *a=new int[N];
> ```

If `N` is equal to 10, this is what happens in memory:

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ^
  |
+-|-+
| * | a
+---+
```

That is, you create an array of 10 integers on the heap, and `a` points to the first of those integers.